# TeX Live ignores TEXINPUTS, maybe kpathsea problem

Tags: texinputs, kpathsea

for a long time my TeX files imported the file `~/lib/tex/mylib.tex`,
using the assignment `TEXINPUTS=".:~/lib/tex:"` and referencing this
file with `\input{mylib}`.

after changing from Suse linux to Debian 10 (buster) that method failed.

in order to pinpoint the problem i tried the following:

```
mkdir d1
touch d1/f1.tex
mkdir d2
touch d2/f2.tex

kpsewhich --path="d1:d2" f1.tex  # A
d1/f1.tex
kpsewhich --path="d1:d2" f2.tex  # B
# no result

kpsewhich --path="d2:d1" f1.tex  # C
# no result
kpsewhich --path="d2:d1" f2.tex  # D
d2/f2.tex
```

to my surprise the result depends on the order of path elements in the
path string. what can i do to get the intended result in the cases B
(d2/f2.tex) and C (d1/f1.tex)?

info: 'kpsewhich' belongs to the package
'texlive-binaries/oldstable,now 2018.20181218.49446-1 amd64'.

Comment: FWIW: the behavior is the same in version 6.3.3 of kpathsea from the 2021 texlive.

Comment: That said if instead of using the `--path=` syntax, I set the path using `TEXINPUTS`, the output is as expected. (And indeed I have not problems with inputs the way you mentioned.) (Can you try `TEXINPUTS='d1/:d2/' kpsewhich f2.tex`)?

Answer (score 2):

i tried the following under debian 10:

```
export -n TEXINPUTS # cleanup
unset TEXINPUTS     # cleanup

TEXINPUTS='d1/:d2/' kpsewhich f2.tex    # E
d2/f2.tex

TEXINPUTS='d1/:d2/'         # F
kpsewhich f2.tex
# no result

export TEXINPUTS            # G
kpsewhich f2.tex
d2/f2.tex
```

as can be seen from case 'F', under debian it is not enough to create the **shell variable** `TEXINPUTS` and assigning it a value. furthermore it is necessary to make `TEXINPUTS` an **environment variable** by exporting it (s.a. https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-variables-export).

my `/etc/bash.bashrc.local` contained step 'F' only. this worked under SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES) 11 SP4 (11.4) but not under debian. i think the debian behaviour is correct only. a reason for the suse-behaviour could be, that some nested suse script contained a 'set +o allexport' statement.

Answer (score 0):

TeX live, on most platforms, will look for a user input tree in `~/texmf/tex`¹<sup>,</sup>²<sup>,</sup>³. In most cases, the simplest approach is to simply put your input files there or in its subdirectories, or if you want to keep the files elsewhere to make a symlink to those other directories in `~/texmf/tex`.

---

1. On MacOS, it looks instead for `~/Library/texmf/tex`.
2. While Windows doesn't use the same syntax, the effect is the same, it will look in the `texmf\tex` subdirectory of the user's home directory.
3. Other subdirectories of `~/texmf` are used for things like Metafont sources, BibTeX inputs, etc.